Tombs of Ancients
This is part 68 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
The top grid here is a Yin-yang puzzle. Shade some cells in the grid so that shaded and unshaded cells both form a single orthogonally connected area and no 2x2 square is fully shaded or unshaded. Cells containing a black circle must be shaded, and cells containing a white circle must be unshaded. Once you’ve solved the Yin-yang, use some of the given 24 pieces from the bottom grid to find out the final answer.
Today I have visited an archaeological site featuring the remains of a very ancient civilisation. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.

Solve on Penpa+


Gladys will return in At the Crossroads.

wait why are you telling us where gladys is going to be next time? isn't that the whole point of the puzzles?

Jafe is telling us the name of the next puzzle, not the answer ;)

The rules of ying-yang are not complete.  No 2x2 square is colored like a checkerboard.

@FlorianF Doesn't that rwquirement follow from the stated rules? I can't come up with an example grid with a 2x2 checkerboard that would meet the rules stated here.

Of course you are right.  You cannot have a 2x2 checkerboard pattern and still have both regions orthogonally connected.  So no more objection.

Gladys is visiting

 Mohenjo-daro

Solution

 

Step-by-step

 A basic deduction of Yin-yang is that any two cells of same colour on the border must be connected through the border. Since at least one of R4C9, R5C9 and one of R8C6, R8C7 must be black while one of R6C9, R7C9 must be white, we know that the black region must cover clockwise the border from R8C6 to R6C9


 Next, we can colour some cells just based on the connectivity and 2x2 rules


 Another basic deduction of Yin-yang is that in any 2x2 region the two colours cannot "cross" each other. This gives us R3C4 and R6C7


 And the rest is filled up with just those basic deductions



Couldn’t we also place the other N piece on R4C3?

@Jujustum Argh, you're right. I actually "fixed" that at the last minute by changing one of the N pieces slightly but looks like I somehow edited the wrong one. D'oh!

I've edited the question to remove that ambiguity (shaded one more cell in piece 16) and edited your answer to correspond to the edited question. Sorry about that! I should have done a full double-check again after making a last-minute edit.

@Jafe No worries, thanks for the nice puzzle as always! I wouldn't have even noticed the ambiguity so good catch from Jujustum!
